# how to add virtual input microphone for android phones

Tags: android, audio, stream, microphone

I need voice change application for android, but now we can't access to on-call audio stream in most of phones.

I decided to do same with virtual microphone like that:

create virtual microphone and set it like default microphone, at call, modulated audio stream going to any path and virtual microphone reading and transmit it by GSM.

How can I do it?

Who have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? I am trying to create something that requires a similar feature.

Comment: No :(  it's possible, but very hard to do. There is no libraries or docs to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do you know it's possible? Can I see how?